# Invalid invocation issue with async-await functionality in server component; specifically in dynamic route

Tags: next.js, prisma, nextjs-dynamic-routing

When I click on "add new", I get the following error:

> PrismaClientKnownRequestError: Invalid `prisma.billboard.findUnique()` invocation:
> Inconsistent column data: Malformed ObjectID: provided hex string representation must be exactly 12 bytes, instead got: "new", length 3.
> at async BillboardPage (billboards/[billboardId]/page.tsx:14:23)
> digest: "1047868513"`

```
const BillboardPage = async ({
  params
}: {
  params: { billboardId: string }
}) => {
  console.log("Billboard ID:", params.billboardId);
  const billboard = await prismadb.billboard.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: params.billboardId
    }
  });

  return ( 
    <div className="flex-col">

      <div className="flex-1 space-y-4 p-8 pt-6">
        <BillboardForm initialData={billboard} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BillboardPage;
```

Route component:

```
export const BillboardClient = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const params = useParams();
   return (
        <>
        <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
          <Heading 
          title="Billboards (0)"
          description="Manage Billboards for your store"
          />
          <Button  onClick={() => router.push(`/${params.storeId}/billboards/new`)}>
            <Plus className="mr-w h-4 w-4"/>
            Add New
          </Button>
        </div>
        <Separator />
        </>
    )
}
```

How can I fix the error?

Comment: Thank you for listening :) Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) as quick start and have a look at the help center. This helps a lot to get onboarded. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have bad data in your database; possibly a row where ID equals `new`, if the error message can be trusted. The value can't be converted to an ObjectID and an error is thrown.

Search the database and delete or fix invalid ID values.

Comment: When I convert the BillboardPage component to a client-side component and use useEffect, clicking on 'Add New' works fine, allowing me to create a billboard. However, when I search for an ID in the URL, it redirects to creating a new billboard instead of editing an existing one. Conversely, when I convert the component back to a server-side component and search for that same ID, it redirects to editing the billboard. The issue seems to be that on the client-side, it doesn't open the edit billboard, while on the server-side, it doesn't open the create billboard.